# seaborn is not working with set_xticklabels() as expected

Tags: python, seaborn, x-axis

I'm trying to change the rotation on of the x axis labels on a seaborn linechart. However when I run the below code I just get a large list as output and a graph without x labels:

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(15,5)})
chart = sns.lineplot(y = top_deaths['Deaths'], x = top_deaths['Date'], data = top_deaths, hue ='Country/Region')
x = chart.get_xticklabels()
chart.set_xticklabels(x, rotation = 45)


[Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, ''),
 Text(0, 0, '')]
```

[image: Graph]

The dataframe I'm referencing looks like this:
[image: DataFrame]

Why is this list being produced? Why aren't they x ticks rotating,and how can I get them to rotate?
Any help is greatly appreciated:).

Answer (score 5):

You need to force seaborn to draw the plot before get the xticklabel:

```py
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(15,5)})
chart = sns.lineplot(y = top_deaths['Deaths'], x = top_deaths['Date'], data = top_deaths, hue ='Country/Region')
chart.figure.canvas.draw()
x = chart.get_xticklabels()
chart.set_xticklabels(x, rotation = 45)
```

I don't know why this is necessary in seaborn, but this is how it works.

Comment: Thank you!  This works but I still get the output of [Text(0, 0, ''), repeated.  Any idea how I can prevent Text(0,0 ") from being printed?

Comment: Put a `;` at the end `chart.set_xticklabels(x, rotation = 45);`